# Logic confusion in finding way to do Reporting with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, data-analysis

I am out of logic for a high priority task. Task is to find a way to report how the customer activity changes over time in a vehicle sharing app. We have a view written in BigQuery which says whether the customer is actively using the service for 30 , 90 days and he is a frequent user or not. Customer using service more than a particular threshold per month is referred to as high user, ultra user respectively based on threshold crossed. We classified the user as active for 30 / 90 days , non active user , high / ultra user. But this category changes with time. For example:
- active user for past 30 days can become non active user.
- non-active user who never used the service can all of a sudden become high/ ultra user for the present month and from next month may not use service at all

We have data for all the service used by the customer.

Really confused and stuck with finding the best strategy to find how much value and volume is generated by customer types.What I am looking is to report this in historical context.

Any idea is highly appreciated. This is very much important for me right now and I am really stuck.

This is a portion of the BigQuery view I have right now.

[image]

These are the meanings of the column names:

id : The id of customer
non_active_customer : Customer who never used service but registered app

non_active_customer_14 : Customer not active for past 14 days
non_active_customer_30 : Customer not active for past 30 days

active_customer_90_int : 1 if customer used service in past 90 days 0 otherwise

active_customer_30_int : 1 if customer used service in past 30 days 0 otherwise

heavy_customer_int  : 1 If customer used service more than a particular threshold in past 90 days 0 otherwise

heavy_customer_30_int : 1 If customer used service more than a particular threshold in past 30 days 0 otherwise

ultra_customer_int : 1 If customer used service more than a very high threshold 0 otherwise

ultra_customer_30_int : 1 If customer used service more than a very high threshold in 30 days 0 otherwise

But every month the result of this view changes. Therefore the customer type also changes( I mean the values in the columns change). The requirement is to report this in historical context so that we know how the customer changes from one type to another over time.

I am not sure if its a good idea to take the logic from view and run the query for every month and save the  data into warehouse with date mapped to it? I think in this way, I can know the  customertype of a user for a particular month and in this way I can track how the customer type changes.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I have done something similar, I had to build a group point-in-time table to be able to say "this was the performance of group x on date y", so for each day (going back as far as you want to report on historically) you'd store a customer ID and their current group status.

Comment: @BenP Thanks for your awesome reply. It gives me some direction to move on. Right now we have a view which gives the present status of user giving true / false values for a particular category as different columns in query result. However  next month it can be different.  Can you please provide more details about the implementation logic?

Comment: Sure thing, could you update your original question with some specific questions and I'll provide a more detailed reply and try to answer them.

Comment: @BenP I have updated question please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to report on customer group as they were at a point in time then it may helpful to build tables that store this information, because as you quite rightly say, if your working with a live view it's only gonig to show you "now".

For example, if you want to track this change every month, then build a table every month * that shows the customer ID and the segments that each ID was in, then you can cross reference these customer ID's against your main database tables and summarize stats at a group level.

I had the same challenge with historical data, in order to populate this i wrote a python script that ran customer segments with a rolling window, to automate the process of looking back in time - assuming you have the data you could do this too. You may also want to explore [BigQuery Scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) (in Beta at the time of writing) as a way to do this within the BigQuery UI.

.* This would be same query that power's your view, but you'd save in in a table, perhaps data stamped, to show the point in time it corresponds too.

Comment: I think I can use apache airflow / cloud composer to run an ETL task ( which contains the query  in view with some modifications) every month to save the data.

Comment: Yes indeed, and you could also set Airflow to back-date the date for you when you run it for the first time!